# Angular2 Template App

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, yeoman

I am new to Angular2 client side development and i want to have a sort of a base project structure so i could go on from there.

I have found that you could create the structure using yeoman and angular2 generator but it seems that it builds on top of very early version 2.0.x.
Maybe there is an up-to-date generator?

I have also found some examples on github but all of them vary a bit from each other when it comes to structure and the content.

Regarding the site that i am developing, it would be a small company website with some static content, blog with comments, polls and an ability to sign-up / log in (i will be using Play as the backend). Nothing special so i guess a single module angular2 app would do.

Thanks in advance for the advice and tips on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-cli will help you out. and its up-to-date regularly. also it will help you in production deployment. and much more things goes on.

Comment: Have installed with 'npm install -g angular-cli'. Then according to instuction you should scaffold your project using 'ng' command. I have installed that also using 'npm install -g ng' but Linux does not recognize that command anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: after installing npm install -g angular-cli you no need to install npm install -g ng. ng command is from angular-cli package. so after installing angular-cli go to your terminal and type ng.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did. Ng got installed with version 0.0.0-rc6 and there is a link in ~/.npm-global/bin. This dir is part of my $PATH and still the command is not recognized.

Comment: npm install -g angular-cli install this using without using SUDO.

Comment: here is github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/503

try this work around: add a alias in your bash_profile

alias ng="<path to>/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng"

Comment: try to install angular-cli latest version 1.0.0-beta.21.

Comment: Adding the alias helped

Answer (score 0):

If you want configurable build processes, it's better to start with https://github.com/angular/quickstart else go for angular-cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli